# KeyError when setting field specific error on def clean()

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a multiple choice field in my form.

```
paymentoption = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(BasisOfPricingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
    self.fields['paymentoption'].choices = [(t.id, t.title) for t in PaymentOption.objects.all()]

def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super(BasisOfPricingForm, self).clean()
      paymentoption = cleaned_data.get('paymentoption')

      if paymethod1 == 3 and len(paymentoption) == 0:            
            self.add_error('paymentoption', 'You must select at lease one Offline Payment Option if users must pay in person or over the phone.')
```

When the conditions of the error are met, I get a "KeyError" on field ''paymentoption'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a couple of hints:

**First, most of the time you don't have (and don't want to mess with the form's initializer)**

Instead of initializing the values of your `paymentoption` choices in the form's `__init__` is better to create a `CustomMultipleChoiceFiled` for that matter.

For example:

```
class PaymentOptions(MultipleChoiceField):
   
    def __init__(self, choices=None, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentOptions, self).__init__(choices=choices, **kwargs)
        if choices is None:
            self.choices = # ...
```

then you can use it without messing around with the Form's `__init__`.

**Second, do not reimplement `clean` if not absolutely necessary** you can add a method called `clean_paymentoption` and perform there all the necessary validation.

You can read about this in the documentation:

> The **`clean_<fieldname>()`** method is called on a form subclass – where **`<fieldname>`** is replaced with the name of the form field attribute. This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is not passed any parameters. You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method, above, has already cleaned the data once).
>
> For example, if you wanted to validate that the contents of a CharField called **serialnumber** was unique, **clean_serialnumber()** would be the right place to do this. You don’t need a specific field (it’s just a CharField), but you want a formfield-specific piece of validation and, possibly, cleaning/normalizing the data.
>
> The return value of this method replaces the existing value in cleaned_data, so it must be the field’s value from cleaned_data (even if this method didn’t change it) or a new cleaned value.

In your case it could be:

```
def clean_paymentoption(self):
    paymentoption = self.cleaned_data.get('paymentoption', None)
    if paymethod1 == 3 and len(paymentoption) == 0:            
        self.add_error('paymentoption', 'You must select at lease one Offline Payment Option if users must pay in person or over the phone.')
```

And again you avoid another `super` call, and `super` calls are a good thing to avoid when you start to get errors hard to track like this you just posted here.